# I need a deeper understanding of the state of being and the quality of being?

Tags: semantics, linguistics, lexicon, abstract-nouns

the word "approvableness" means - The state or quality of being approvable

When is approvableness used as a state of being approvable? And when is approvableness used as a quality of being appprovable?

Comment: *Attractiveness* is indeed the quality of being attractive: I am not sure what "a quaility of being attractive" would be. Please clarify

Comment: Not sure either, the definition of a qaulity of being was taken from the here https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attractiveness#English

Comment: @TimLymington I started writing up an answer but I noticed that sometimes "quality of" also means "state of".  Personally I would reserve the word "quality of" for specific attributes.  Words like "attractive" or "nice" or "beautiful" don't really mean anything.  "attractive because he had good posture or a warm smile" I think are actual qualities.

Comment: @TimLymington  but I think I'm splitting hairs semantically

Comment: @Tom: I think there is a fair question somewhere here, hinging on the difference between *state* and *quality*; but this is not it. If OP doesn't edit, you could have a go yourself, perhaps: if nobody does, this will certainly be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Approvableness* shows up in dictionaries; but outside of dictionaries Google Books shows me only five uses since 1900, and three of those are from a single book on *Doing Phenomenology*, whose author's native language appears to have been German.

I recommend you not use this word at all. The ordinary noun derivative for adjectives of the form *VERBable* is *VERBability*, so a better choice would be ***approvability***. It's not exactly common, but Google Books lists several dozen uses in the current century.

As for your *state* vs *quality* question: this is pretty standard dictionary language for surrounding the meaning of a term when you can't quite pin down an actual 'meaning'. *State* and *quality* aren't distinct entities: they're two metaphors—where an entity stands and what it is like—for describing the endstate of recategorizing a verb as a noun.